# How do I use ng-repeat properly on this json string?

Tags: json, angularjs

I updated a random "ng-repeat test fiddle" I found via google and put in double quotes just like my json string has: http://jsfiddle.net/tRxzr/602/

But here's mine and it doesn't work. I'm trying to repeat Li elements:
http://jsfiddle.net/tRxzr/604/

The json string I'm getting back from the server is:

```
[{"UserId":"testuser","DisplayName":"Test User"}]
```

Is this not Angular JS "repeatable"? Ultimatley I'm trying to get this into an ng-options attribute for a select, just doing this ng-repeat with a list as a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your :

```
{{obj.UserId}} // {{obj.DisplayName}}
```

with :

```
{{o.UserId}} // {{o.DisplayName}}
```

In your  `ng-repeat="o in obj"` you want to access `o` properties, and not `obj` ones

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
{{obj.UserId}}
```

with

```
{{o.UserId}}
```

obj is the set, o is the individual record you want to display.